# Xcode Organizer Crashes no record with account?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode6, crash-reports

i follow Analyzing Crash Reports

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

and still no data present.

do i miss something which dose not write on Analyzing Crash Reports.

i checked all step

[image]

but still like this,
[image]

Comment: Please, add a screenshot or more details about the crash.

Comment: i had been check the step on Analyzing Crash Reports,but still like photo

Comment: Hi Sean, I'm facing same issue.. Have you found a solution ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Dear Sam,my apple id is a member  of other Apple ID but no allow to use iTunes connet so I make my account can use and then crashes report just appear.

Answer (score 3):

We also had this issue for a while now and were struggling to find the cause.

Intercepting Xcode's requests showed us the actual error when Xcode tried to load latest crash reports:

> The updated Apple Developer Program License Agreement needs to be
>   reviewed. In order to update your existing apps and submit new apps to
>   the App Store, the user with the Legal role (Team Agent) must review
>   and accept the updated agreement in their account on the developer
>   website.

This is the same error message we get when pressing the "Download dSYMs…" button.

This was confusing, since we've already accepted all agreements we could find in both, the Member Center and in iTunes Connect.

Later we found out that we do not just have to accept the agreements for our app's App Store account but **we have to accept the agreements for all App Store accounts linked to the same Apple ID**. So it depends on your Apple ID which explains why sometimes only some developers are affected by the issue.

**TLDR:** If your Apple ID is linked with multiple App Store accounts (in Member Center and iTunes Connect) make sure that for **all** of these accounts the agreements are accepted.

Comment: One of those times when +1 just doesn't do. Seriously unacceptable Apple, that I can't download crashlogs for *my* app when a freelance client, whose account I have no control over, hasn't accepted *their* contract.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing in my two cents here- In my case, I wasn't seeing any crash reports except some from months and several versions ago. Turns out I had some updated agreement from Apple I haven't signed, and as soon as signed them, all the crash reports started to flow into my Xcode.

[image]

Mysterious as always, Apple, when it comes to Xcode.